# 2000 Simple products in a configurable product

Tags: magento-1.7, import, magmi, simple-product, associate-products

I am trying to associate 2000 simple products with one configurable product.

The problem is Excel has a limitation on the length of a cell. I can not put all the SKUs of simple products in one cell.

I am using Magmi to import my products. Magento version is CE 1.7.0.2

Associating simples with using two seperate files is also not working since the second update overrides the first one!

Is there a way to handle that? Or do I need to change my logic? Instead of using that many simples should I do something else?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you want 2000 simple products in a single configurable product?

Comment: I have 6 dropdown options per config, every dropdown has 6 options which can be selected. After all options are selected there is one simple product which matches with all selected options. That is why I have 2000 simples for that config.

Comment: Use a plain text editor to edit your data instead of Excel.

Comment: I did try that too, I exported the data directly to a CSV file instead of excel and I saw that limitation did not apply on that file. But when I imported it via magmi it still associated only 910 simple products to the configurable.
So I thought there is an other limitation but what I understand from your comment is there is no other limitation on Magmi or Magento. 
If this is the case then that CSV file should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem via removing the simples_skus field from the import file and using the automatic association logic which depends on the SKUs of configs and associated simples. This worked pretty well since our SKUs are already designed with that logic. Simples first Configs after.

Cheers

Comment: after the time limit is passed I will!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know there was a time limit :)